# Can't make PDO rewind work with PDO::FETCH_ORI_ABS

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to scan several times the variable and using mysql_data_seek I had no problems. Now that I'm trying PDO I can't make it work.

I use it like this:

```
while($rowAssistant = $rowSetAssistantsProject->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_ABS, 0)){
```

but it doesn't go inside the while (I guess because it is on the end of $rowSetAssistantsProject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `mysql_data_seek` in PDO and the current mysql-php connections do not support cursors.  What you should do instead is pull all your data into an array and iterate over that.

```
$rows = $rowSetAssistantsProject->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($rows as $row) {
    // Process rows
}

// Where you would have reset mysql_data_seek back to 0 if it existed

foreach($rows as $row) {
    // More row processing
}
```

Once your data is in array form you can place a cursor on the array using the `reset` function like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14860741/3220865) does.  But the code above is what I have had to do since I moved to PDO.  Hope that helps.