# Using PDO::FETCH_ORI_ABS with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am running some performance tests on several ways of getting both limited and offsetted data and total number of rows from a query. The naive way is to run the query twice, once for total number of rows, and a second time with `LIMIT OFFSET` clause to get the actual data.

I am trying to do it now with a single query, where I receive all data and use `fetch` with `FETCH_ORI_ABS` to select only the data I need, but it doesn't seem to work. I get data starting from row 1 to "offset + limit".

This is the code:

```
function method2($pdo, $query, $limit, $offset) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
    $stmt->execute();
    $totalrows = $stmt->rowCount();

    $data = [];
    for ($i = $offset; $i < max($totalrows, $offset + $limit); $i++) {
        $data[] = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_ABS, $i);
    }

    return array("totalrows"=>$totalrows, "data"=>$data);
}
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295396/cant-make-pdo-rewind-work-with-pdofetch-ori-abs), telling me there is no support for cursors, but it is from 2014. I didn't find any other resource on possible support.

Comment: You could do it is a subquery in the single query... but thats two queries as well.

Comment: Thing is I have no real control over the query. They are written by other developers and given to the application in an XML file.